# Find $\lim_{(x,y) \to (0,0)}\frac{\sin(x - y)}{\sqrt{x} + \sqrt{y}}$

Tags: limits

I'm trying to find the $\lim_{(x,y) \to (0,0)}$ $\dfrac{\sin(x - y)}{\sqrt x + \sqrt y}$ and I know the answer is $0$ (used WolframAlpha for that), but I need to understand why.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note that for $x,y>0$, we have
$$\dfrac{\sin(x-y)}{\sqrt{x} + \sqrt{y}} = \dfrac{\sin(x-y)}{x-y} \cdot (\sqrt{x} - \sqrt{y})$$
Can you now conclude what you want?

Comment: can you walk me through it. I still don't understand

Comment: @marisbest2 Is the identity clear?

Comment: yes. I had that already but was unable to continue from there

Comment: @marisbest2 Take limits. Can you see that the limit of $ \sqrt{x} - \sqrt{y}$ is 0? Now, all that remains to show is that the limit of the first term is not infinite, to conclude that the limit of the product is indeed 0.

Comment: Got it now. Thank you.